# Calcular pi com python e uso de recursividade

Tags: python, recursão

Calcular pi pela formula `pi=(s*32)**(1/3)`, sendo `s=(1/1^3)-(1/3^3)+(1/5^3)`...  Quantidade de `s` determinado pelo usário. Deve ser desenvolvido em [python](/questions/tagged/python) com uso de recursividade. Não estou conseguindo obter o resultado esperado, conseguem me ajudar a encontrar o erro, fazendo o favor.

```py
def test(n):
    if n <= 0:
        return False
    else:
        return True

def sum(n,a,p):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return (-1) ** a/ ((p + sum(n - 1, a + 1, p + 2) ** 3) * 32) ** (1 / 3)

n = int(input("Enter the number of the term you want to calculate: "))

if test(n):
    a = 2
    p = 1

    print("Total: ", sum(n, a, p))
else:
    print("Error")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O problema principal está na sua função `sum`, que está calculando incorretamente o valor da somatória da série.

Uma forma possível para montar essa função, é analisar os termos individuais da série e obter a regra de geração para cada elemento:

```
s=(1/1^3)-(1/3^3)+(1/5^3)....
```

Os 2 pontos importantes aqui são:

*1º)* O denominador da fração é formado pelo cubo dos números ímpares

*2º)* O sinal dos termos pares é positivo e dos ímpares é negativo, ou, também pode ser analisado como: o sinal inverte a cada termo (sendo o primeiro, positivo)

A expressão que gera um termo, dada a sua posição (`n`) pode ser montada da seguinte forma:

```
((-1)**(n+1)) + (1/(n*2-1)**3)
```

Sendo `((-1)**(n+1))` a parte que inverte o sinal:

```
n=1 => positivo
n=2 => negativo
n=3 => positivo
...
```

E `(1/(n*2-1)**3)` é a parte que calcula o valor do termo: 1 dividido por um número ímpar elevado ao cubo.

A função recursiva `serie` pode, então, ser obtida assim:

```
def serie(n):
  if n == 0:
    return 0
  else:
    return serie(n-1) + ((-1)**(n+1)) * (1 / (n*2-1)**3)
```

**OBS**: `sum` é uma função interna do Python. Procure utilizar nomes diferentes das funções internas para as suas funções

A partir do resultado de uma posição da série, você pode calcular o valor de `PI` pela segunda fórmula.

Exemplos, variando o valor de `n`:

```
(serie(1)*32)**(1/3)
3.1748021039363987

(serie(3)*32)**(1/3)
3.1437708364187786

(serie(10)*32)**(1/3)
3.1415260879295057

(serie(100)*32)**(1/3)
3.1415925860524654

(serie(1000)*32)**(1/3)
3.1415926535222463

(serie(2000)*32)**(1/3)
3.14159265358135
```

Comment: Obrigado Gomiero por me ajudar a resolver esse problema. Obrigado também pela explicação detalhada, foi muito útil sua ajuda.